# PHP - Displaying multiple databases on one page

Tags: php, sql, dbconnection

This is my first project/attempt using php so please bare with. My question is I am using a script to connect to my server and i am trying to get all the databases to appear on one page. The first error tells me I can not re declare function, I get that so I made some changes but when i do change it the database fails to appear yet the error is gone.

My thoughts are because i'm changing "output_header" and "output_row" my connection script will not pick it up.

```
<?php 
require_once('phpconnectionscript.php');
echo '<table border="1">';
output_header();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare 
 ('SELECT * FROM DogIdentity;'); 
 $stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
echo output_row($row);
}
echo '</table>'; 
?>

<?php function output_row($row){
$oid = $row['Breed'];
$dob=$row['Colour'];
$fna=$row['Weight_KG'];
$lna=$row['Size'];

$rowoutput="<tr><td>$oid</td>
 <td>$dob</td><td>$fna</td>
<td>$lna</td></tr>";
return $rowoutput;
}
?>

<?php
function output_header(){ 
$pdo = $GLOBALS['pdo']; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare 
("DESCRIBE DogIdentity");
$stmt->execute(); 
$fields = $stmt->
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo "<tr>"; 
foreach ($fields as $value){ 
   echo "<th>$value</th>";
}
echo "</tr>"; }
?>

<br><br>

<?php function output_row1($row){
$oid = $row['OwnerID'];
$dob=$row['DOB'];
$fna=$row['firstname'];
$lna=$row['lastname'];
$ema=$row['email'];

$rowoutput="<tr><td>$oid</td>
 <td>$dob</td><td>$fna</td>
<td>$lna</td><td>$ema</td></tr>";
return $rowoutput;
}
?>

<?php
function output_header1(){ 
$pdo = $GLOBALS['pdo']; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare 
("DESCRIBE Owner");
$stmt->execute(); 
$fields = $stmt->
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
echo "<tr>"; 
foreach ($fields as $value){ 
   echo "<th>$value</th>";
}
echo "</tr>"; }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide the full error messages.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are having error because you are using function before their declaration. At the 4th line you are calling `output_header();` but it is not yet declare, appart if it has been declare in `require_once('phpconnectionscript.php');`.

Comment: In PHP you can define functions anywhere in the codebase; they do not have to be defined before being called.

Comment: ah ok !! i don't have habit to do that, but it is good to know !